# Pass selector into javascript function

Tags: javascript, function

i have a js function that insert some code into exsiting html.
HTML

```
<div id="filteredProducts">
    <!--load by js-->
</div>

<div id="filteredplaces">
    <!--load by js-->
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="bucket">
    </div>
</div>
```

js code

```
var myfun = function (data) {
    if (data.form_is_valid) {
        $("#filtered1").html(data.html);
        toggleLight();
    }
```

I need further abstract it to take another paramter so that i can insert data.html into any selector. So "#filtered1" will become a parameter pass into this function.
For example (Not sure if it works)

```
var myfun = function (data, sel) {
    if (data.form_is_valid) {
        $(sel).html(data.html);
        toggleLight();
    }
```

Ideally i'd like to do following:

```
myfun(data,".container .bucket")
```

or

```
myfun(data,"#filteredplaces")
```

Comment: your code looks like it should work, have you tried it to verify?

Comment: If you haven't tried it, what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
const myFunction = (data, selector) => {
    if (data.isFormValid) {
        $(selector).html(data.html);
        // toggleLight();
    }
};
myFunction({ isFormValid: true, html: '<h1>Hello</h1>'}, '.class1,.class2')
```

This seems to work as you intended. I just tested with the last line, and it does what you need.

Perhaps, you missed that you need a comma in between the classes when you are targeting multiple